# DB2 to round calculation to exactly 2 decimals

Tags: sql, db2, decimal

I have a column called AMOUNT in a db2 table, it's type is DECIMAL(15,2).
I am doing the following calculation:

```
ROUND(AMOUNT / 110 * 10,2)
```

For an amount value of 2831.98 I'd expect 257.45, but it gives me 257.4.

I tried

```
CAST(AMUNT / 110 * 10 as DECIMAL(15,2))
```

But it did not work.I saw that if I change 110 to 110.0, it even cuts the one decimal.
Can someone help me out?

Comment: Your queries appear to be working https://dbfiddle.uk/ca0O4sOu

Comment: What's your Db2 platform and version? You may get such a "strange" result, if your `110` data type is not `int`, but `dec (x, 16)` for [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/bq9-RXLg).

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why it works but this was the solution:

```
round(round(AMOUNT,2) / 110 * 10, 2)
```